# How to leverage the FuelUX DataGrid "loaded" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fuelux

I need to bind a click event to `<a>` tags in a FuelUX DataGrid column that are dynamically added via a custom formatter.

The formatter is working as expected, however, I'm not sure how I should go about binding the click event handler. I would prefer to do so in an unobtrusive way.

The DataGrid is supposed to have a ["loaded" event hook](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#datagrid), but there isn't an example of how to use this event. Can someone please point me to an example? Google is coming up short for me.

The only reference I can find to the event is on [163 of datagrid.js](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/src/datagrid.js):

```
self.$element.trigger('loaded');
```

I'm assuming that means I need to define a "loaded" function on the object, but where/how? My DataGrid is:

```
$('#jobs').datagrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    itemsText: 'Available Positions',
    itemText: 'Available Position';
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking up the reference for [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in the jQuery API, all I needed to do was add an `'on'` handler to the datagrid:

```
$('#jobs').datagrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    itemsText: 'Available Positions',
    itemText: 'Available Position';
}).on('loaded', function() {
    console.log('DataGrid loaded');
);
```